# ReactJS is not loading/rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Today when I started up the iMac to continue working on the ReactJS app...it doesn't load...

What I mean by "load" is, it doesn't display the content of any page.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined

If you need the code of App.js and index.js
here they are:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './pages/Header';
import Footer from './pages/Footer';

import './css/App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Header />

            {/*Content*/}
            <div> App Page </div>

        <Footer />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import { Router, Route, History } from 'react-router';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

// CSS
import './css/index.css';

// Pages
import About from './pages/About';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Cart from './pages/Cart';
import Thanks from './pages/Thanks';
import Faq from './pages/Faq';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';
import Error from './pages/Error';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={History}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/pages/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/pages/Register" component={Register}/>
        <Route path="/pages/Cart" component={Cart}/>
        <Route path="/pages/Thanks" component={Thanks}/>
        <Route path="/pages/Error" component={Error}/>
        <Route path="/pages/Faq" component={Faq}/>
        <Route path="/pages/Contact" component={Contact}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: console errors?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/wng0C

Comment: I didn't have iMac, I have MacBook Pro... and then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, your history object is undefined. Please try importing `browserHistory` instead of `History` and pass that into your router.

versions before React-Router v4 (Which I am assuming you are using since you are importing `Router`:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

...

....
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
```

React-Router v4:

Instead of importing `Router`/`browserHistory`, you import `browserRouter`, which is a router that creates it's own history instance. it would look like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router';
...

...

<BrowserRouter>
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
```